# After splash screen, redirect to Login screen in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Im newbie to react native mobile development.
I have this problem that, after splash screen, it will redirect to my bottom tab navigation with 5 tabs.
But my expected output is after splash screen, it will redirect/navigate to LOGIN SCREEN, in that LOGIN SCREEN, I have 'FORGOT PASSWORD' and 'REGISTER' label that if tap, user will navigate to each corresponding page. In LOGIN screen also, I have a button "LOGIN" that if click, and this time the user will redirect to bottom tab with 5 screen.s

This is what I've tried.
//app.js

```
//app.js
 <NavigationContainer>
      <BottomTabNavigator/>
 </NavigationContainer>
```

//BottomTabNavigator.js

```
function MyTabsNavigator() {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  function otherNavigation(){
    return(
      <Stack.Navigator  screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
      initialRouteName="Login">
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginModule}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="CreateAccount" component={CreateAccountPage}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPasswordModule}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    )
  }
  function OrderStack() {
    return(
      <Stack.Navigator   screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Orders" component={OrderModule}/>
       
      </Stack.Navigator>
    )
  }

  function StationStack(){
    return(
      <Stack.Navigator   screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
     >
        <Stack.Screen name="Stations" component={StationModule}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Product" component={ProductComponent}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="ProductDetails" component={ProductDetailsComponent}/>
       
      </Stack.Navigator>
      
    )
  }
  function MapStack(){
    return(
      <Stack.Navigator   screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}> 
         <Stack.Screen name="Maps" component={MapModule}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
     
    )
  }

 

  function NotificationStack(){
    return(
      <Stack.Navigator   screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}> 
         <Stack.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationModule}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
     
    )
  }

  function ProfileStack(){
    return(
      <Stack.Navigator   screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}> 
         <Stack.Screen name="Profiles" component={ProfileModule}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
     
    )
  }

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Station"
    
    >

      <Tab.Screen name="Order" component={OrderStack}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Station" component={StationStack}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Map" component={MapStack}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Notification" component={NotificationStack}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStack}/>
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `OtherNavigator` component in navigation container and in OtherNavigator add a `Stack.Screen` with `BottomTabNavigator` .

```
 //app.js
 <NavigationContainer>
      <OtherNavigator/>
 </NavigationContainer>
```

then in `OtherNavigator.js`

```
export default function OtherNavigation(){
return(
  <Stack.Navigator  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
  }}
  initialRouteName="Login">
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginModule}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="CreateAccount" component={CreateAccountPage}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPasswordModule}/>
<Stack.Screen name="BottomTabNavigator" component={BottomTabNavigator}/>
  </Stack.Navigator>
)
```

}

Comment: but still sir, my  <BottomTabNavigator/> in app.js will stay as is? I will just add the OtherNavigator?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/8pl6MB

I tried in my app.js sir but I receive this error- > Error: A navigator can only contain 'Screen', 'Group' or 'React.Fragment' as its direct children (found 'MyTabsNavigator'). To render this component in the navigator, pass it in the 'component' 
prop to 'Screen'.

Comment: did you created a saprate file of component for OtherComponent, and remove it from tabNavigator component

Comment: ah yes, I will just include in my bottomTab file?